# 3dscatter plot for trading data

Tags: r, plotly, color-coding

I'm experimenting for quit some time with the tables of the trade.sqlite3 database. I came up with a combined table of the import and export table.

[A csv-file of the table can be downloaded here :](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13803865/Total_Value.html)

[Added a virus scan of the file as well](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/214a44637d887d23dcc6848c322a46bc40a93d06729ac170b27fc19cb73582cc/detection)

`str` of the table to get an idea how it looks like :

> Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  300 obs. of  4 variables:
>   $ year    : num  2002 2002 2002 2002 2002 ...
>   $ category: Factor w/ 10 levels "0--Food And Live Animals",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
>   $ value   : num  4.94e+08 2.88e+08 9.40e+08 4.96e+07 7.76e+06 ...
>   $ type    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Exp","Imp": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

Now I want to plot this table using `plot_ly`.

I came up with the following idea :

```
library(plotly)
total_val <- read.csv("Total_Value")
plot_ly(data = total_val, x = total_val$year, 
y = total_val$value, z = total_val$category, color = total_val$category, 
stroke = total_val$category, type = "scatter3d" )
```

I still fight with some problems :
- I want to indicate if a marker is of type import or export.
- Using the color code as I did produces the following warning :

> n too large, allowed maximum for palette Set2 is 8
>   Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors

There are 10 categorys and I need to display them all. Is there a better way to do this despite color coding?

Any other opinions to make the plot more informative are highly recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following [this](https://community.plot.ly/t/different-marker-shapes-in-3d-scatter-plot/4530) I came up with a solution to plot with different shapes the Imp and Exp. The color issue is as easy as specifying the colors using the `colors` argument.

```
total_val$markers <- ifelse(total_val$type == "Exp", "circle", "diamond")
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(data = total_val, x = ~year, 
        y = ~value, z = ~category, color = ~category,
        colors = rainbow(length(levels(total_val$category))),
        text = ~paste('category:', category, '<br>value:', value, '<br>year:', year,
                      '<br>type:', type)) %>%
  add_markers() %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'year'),
                      yaxis = list(title = 'Value'),
                      zaxis = list(title = 'Category')))

p <- plotly_build(p)

for (i in 1:length(p$x$data)) {
  values <- total_val$markers[total_val$category == levels(total_val$category)[i]]
  p$x$data[[i]]$marker$symbol <- values
}
p
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added a new Item and a new Category TOTAL to the table. TOTAL is displayed in the graph as it should but now the symbolic distinction between Exp (circle) and Imp (diamond) is not displayed instead every symbol is circle. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Hello again, thanks for the cuestion because it was a problem with the last `for loop`. When I did `length(p$x)` it was just a coincidence with the number of categories of your data (10 categories), so when you add a new category then `length(p$x)` was not equal to the number of categories (11 categories). Instead, `length(p$x$data)` should be used to take into account all the "layers" of the plotly.  I've already edited the answer with the new solution.

Comment: By the way, to create the new TOTAL variable I used: 
`total_val$year <- factor(total_val$year)

total_val$type <- factor(total_val$type)

total <- aggregate(total_val$value, list(year = total_val$year, type = total_val$type), sum)

names(total)[3] <- "value"

total$category <- "TOTAL"

total_val$markers <- NULL # Erase the past markers

total_val <- rbind(total_val, total)

total_val <- total_val[order(total_val$year),]

total_val$markers <- ifelse(total_val$type == "Exp", "circle", "diamond")`

Comment: I treid your solution but sadly it is not working for me. Here is the new table. Maybe you see the problem Thanks so far anyway. Besided that the code is working great. [Table Update](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13806081/total_val.csv.html)

Comment: I don't know what to say, the new code works for me with your new data

Comment: http://prntscr.com/q4opei

I added a screenshot of my result. I can't understand why it does not work for me but for you. This is something very unusual for code. But at least now I can be sure it is not a code problem. Thanks for the help anyway.